# How do I override the Visual Studio Container Tools debugger volumes in docker-compose.vs.debug.g.yml?

Tags: visual-studio, docker-compose, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-container-tools

My application is a ASP.NET WCF app running on .NET Framework 4.8. I am using Docker for Windows, Visual Studio 2019 and Container Tools with the latest updates.

The app is running in the wcf:4.8 windows contanier image and from the Dockerfile, I copy my sources into a new directory such as 'c:\inetpub\myapp'.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/wcf:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/myapp
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

I've used PowerShell to create the app pool, service accounts, edit bindings, etc. as needed and the app functions, Debugs, etc. as desired. However, my source directory is still **also** mounted to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` regardless of what I do in the compose file.

This is what's generated into the global compose. My custom volume location is simply merged with this and so far I've seen no [.dcproj build parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019) or environment variable that will change this behavior:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  appserver:
    image: appserver:dev
    container_name: AppServer
    build:
      args:
        source: obj/Docker/empty/
      labels:
        com.microsoft.created-by: "visual-studio"
        com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name: "AppServer"
    volumes:
```

**I want this line gone:**

```
      - C:\Source\MyAppSourceDir:C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

```
      - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger:C:\remote_debugger:ro
    entrypoint: cmd /c "start /B C:\\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc & C:\\remote_debugger\\x64\\msvsmon.exe /noauth /anyuser /silent /nostatus /noclrwarn /nosecuritywarn /nofirewallwarn /nowowwarn /timeout:2147483646"
```

Comment: Great question. I have the exact same issue. My base image contains default stuff in  c:\inetpub\wwwroot but VS keeps mounting it's publish folder over the `wwwroot`  directory...